# How to create Windows executable from JAR

Tags: java, jar, exe

I have a simple Java program (lets call it MyProgram.java) that does some I/O, re-names some images, deletes a directory, etc. I've been browsing around S/O looking for a simple way to run a Java program's main method from command prompt. I've compiled the source code into a jar, and tried using Jar2EXE Wizard, however I kept getting an unexpected compilation error that I wasn't getting while running my code from the IDE.

Does any one have either a Jar -> EXE converter solution they've had success with or can walk me through how to run my program from a batch file?

Comment: Does your code have dependency on external libraries.

Comment: "I kept getting an unexpected compilation error that I wasn't getting while running my code from the IDE" - you need to fix those errors first. No wizard can help you here.

Comment: Yes, code uses the Apache commons FileUtils/IOUtils libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [..]or can walk me through how to run my program from a batch file?

The simplest way is to execute:

```
java -jar YOUR_JAR_FILE.jar
```

in your batch file. However this requires a manifest file to be present in your jar file which specifies the Main class to use and jar files it depends on. If you do not want to work with a manifest file you can specify these things manually. If you do not depend on external jar files you can execute:

```
java -cp YOUR_JAR_FILE.jar some.package.Main
```

This will execute the `public static main(String[] args)` method in class some.package.Main contained in YOUR_JAR_FILE.jar.

If there are other jar files you depend on (in your case that would be IOUtils/FileUtils), specify those jar files as well:

```
java -cp YOUR_JAR_FILE.jar:library1.jar:library2.jar some.package.Main
```

(in your case library1 and library2 are IOUtils and FileUtils respectively).

You can specify any number of jar files and you can also use the wildcard `*.jar` to include all files in the current (or another) directory. Note however that you cannot write `*` or `x*.jar` or the like. Only `*.jar` (or `some/directory/*.jar`) is accepted.

In 90% of the times, the order of the jar files does not make any difference. However sometimes it does make a difference: If a resource is loaded from the classpath (could be a class or something as simple as a configuration file), the jar files are searched in the order you specified. If a resource exists in multiple jar files, only the first one found will be used.

Comment: I know the question title is wrong but it seems OP wants to convert jar to exe

Comment: You can specify a classpath in the parameter list too.

Comment: The program compiles fine, and runs fine. However, I get a run time error that I don't get when running the program from the IDE. Do I have to specify my classpath in the batch file as well? Note: My program has dependencies on the apache commons IOUtils/FileUtils

Comment: @kidwit: Sry, I totally forgot about your question. Better late than never: I extended my answer to cover you dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using install4j.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use batch file you can write this:

```
java -jar sources.jar
```

If your code have more than 2 `static void main(String[] args)` you need explicitly hit the method:

```
java -jar sources.jar classes.package.Main
```

Directory structure:

```
-\project\
-\project\run.bat
-\project\sources.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/). It wraps your JARs as executables and provides options for detecting, and handling lack of, the JVM. I've used it on a simple app and it was painless.

Bonus: it is available as a portable app with no installation needed.